# How to forcefully delete a file

Tags: ruby, file-io

When I try to delete a file I am getting acess denied  as error .How should I set the mode of a file or is there any way of deleting a file forcefully with out changing the mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is OS-dependent.

With UNIX/Linux it is neccessary to have write permission for the directory containing the file. If the sticky bit is set on the directory (like on /tmp) you have to be owner of the file, too.

If you're using annother OS you may want to refine your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the permissions of the file and its parent folders. As far as I know there is no way to delete a file forefully without having necessary permissions. Adjusting permissions of a file will differ for different operating systems.

for *nix see: chmod